How to match the content in parentheses using Java
The following is my code, based on jdk17. I want to match the content in the parentheses. I have no problem matching it using the online platform, but I can't match it using Java code.
package com.example.ticket_query;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * "station_train_code": "D29(天津西-齐齐哈尔南)", \(.*-.*\)
 */
class TicketQueryApplicationTest {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*station_train_code.*");
    Pattern stationNamePattern = Pattern.compile("\\(.*-.*\\)");

    @DisplayName(value = "获取所有的车站名称")
    @Test
    void getStationName() {

        String s = "11(adfa-2342)df";
        Matcher stationNames = stationNamePattern.matcher(s);
        if (stationNames.matches()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}

It has bothered me for a long time. Please help me, experts.

(X-Y) implies two tokens. What are those tokens?

You might use something like: record Station(String name, String code);List<Station> stations  = Pattern.compile("\\((.*)-(.*)\\)").matcher(s).results().map(r ->new Station(r.group(1), r.group(2))).toList();

I've replaced the "pattern-matching" tag with the "regex" one here. The former is a particular language feature that lets you match on values inside a data structure, so it wasn't the correct one to use.

You are using the java.util.regex APIs incorrectly.  You should be calling Matcher#find() to check for one or more matches to the pattern.  Also, to access the match, call Matcher#group() and pass the index of the capture group you want.
Also note below that I slightly modified your regex pattern to:
\((.*-.*)\)

This will capture in the first capture group the content inside the parentheses (excluding the parentheses themselves).
Pattern stationNamePattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.*-.*)\\)");
String s = "11(adfa-2342)df";
Matcher stationNames = stationNamePattern.matcher(s);
if (stationNames.find()) {
    System.out.println(stationNames.group(1));  // prints adfa-2342
}

